# how to stop java script Function execution

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function processJasperReport(filePath, fileName, fileType) {

    CheckSecurityForJasperReport(filePath, fileName, fileType);

    //call another funcation to run report                                          }               

    function CheckSecurityForJasperReport(filePath, fileName, fileType) {

    if(security == "true")
    {
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url :"../CheckExecutePriviledge",
            data: "reportpath="+filePath+"&reportname="+fileName,
            success:function(content)
            {  priviledge=content;  
                if( priviledge==false)
                {
                    alert("You do not have permission to access this report");
                    return;
                }
            }   
        });     
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're stopping the execution with `return;`, but there's nothing left to execute. I'm not sure what you're asking..

Comment: Unclear what you are asking?? Explain elaborately.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to stop the execution of the function?

Comment: Which function do you want to "stop"? Are you per-maybe-haps asking how to cancel the ajax request without waiting for the success handler?

Comment: i thought var security = "true" should not be declared globally or pass as parameter?

Comment: when i execute this function i get a alert message and then my processJasperReport funcation will run the belor code that i have written after that function call,
it is not stop execution after return;
can you please give me solution for that.

Comment: @m59 i want to stop my execution after return;

Comment: Then `return` later??

Comment: @user991554 No it is declared globally and work fine.

Comment: @Shoaib Chikat i have to check for security before a funcation execution that's why i have called one function CheckSecurityForJasperReport() inside the processJasperReport funcation , if CheckSecurityForJasperReport() has false in servlet responce than i want to stop my execution of code there only,

Comment: @m59 i want to stop the processJasperReport() funcation based on the
CheckSecurityForJasperReport() funcataion responce.

Comment: @m59 where should i write return statement....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `CheckSecurityForJasperReport` should return/define the further action, instead of directly stopping from there. Quick solution comes to my mind is something like this - 
(optimization of this is possible :-))

```
    function CheckSecurityForJasperReport(filePath, fileName, fileType) {
    var priviledge = false;       
            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                dataType: "json",
                url :"../CheckExecutePriviledge",
                data: "reportpath="+filePath+"&reportname="+fileName,
                success:function(content)
                {  
                   priviledge = content;
                }   
            });           
     return priviledge; 
}

function processJasperReport(filePath, fileName, fileType) {
     // if security is enabled 
var action_go_ahead = CheckSecurityForJasperReport(filePath, fileName, fileType);
if (action_go_ahead){
// proceed 
}else{
// STOP, nothing to do here.!    
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Ved, my problem has solved.

Comment: Great.! If you feel its resolved, you can accept the answer as correct answer, if you want. :-)